# Traduccion sql a eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Alguien sabe como puedo traducir esta consulta a eloquen?

```
select distinct usuario_ad from usuarios where asignacion='null';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo dl siguiente modo

**CON EL QUERY BUILDER FLUENT**

```
$data = \DB::table('usuarios')
    ->distinct('usuario_ad')
    ->where('asignacion', 'null')
    ->get();
```

Al método `distinct()` le pasas entre comillas el nombre de la columna por la cual quieres encontrar valores distintos

El método `where` lo pasas al final y el uso del signo = es opcional

Al final usas `get` para obtener los resultados

**CON El ORM ELOQUENT**

O si tienes un modelo llamado `Usuario` puedes hacerlo de este modo enteramente con Eloquent

```
$data = Usuario::distinct('usuario_ad')
    ->select('usuario_ad')
    ->where('asignacion', 'null')
    ->get();
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para seleccionar columnas específicas de la tabla, entonces después del método `distinct()` invocas al método `select()` y le pasas el nombre de las columnas que deseas; en este caso `usuario_ad`

Comment: Gracias shadow, la traduccion es correcta, aunque asi me devuelve todos los campos, yo solo quiero un campo, que es usuario_ad

Comment: te actualizo la respuesta te parece bien? @zereft

Comment: listo @zereft te actualicé la respuesta con lo que necesitas, revisa la parte final

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente halle la solucion, gracias shadow.

```
$usuariosOpciones =usuarios::
 where('asignacion', 'null')
 ->pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')
 ->unique();
```

Comment: correcto, es otra forma de obtenerlo